# Vue.js computed property not working

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

I have a users data object which has a first_name and last_name and a computed property which returns the full name but the following doesnt seems to work in my v-for directive?

```
new Vue({

        el: '#content',

        data: {
          "users": [
            {
              "id": 3,
              "first_name": "Joe",
              "last_name": "Blogs"
            },
            {
              "id": 3,
              "first_name": "Jane",
              "last_name": "Doe"
            }
          ]
       },
        computed: {
           fullName: function (user) {
                return user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name;
            }

        }

    });



    <tr v-for="user in users | orderBy fullName(user)">
          <td class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
              {{fullName(user)}} 
         </td>
    <tr>
```

Answer (score 36):

I don't believe that a computed property in Vue.js can accept an argument, they are supposed to be able to build themselves without additional interaction. I believe that your fault was that you wrote a method and then tried to register it as a computed property.

So it should be a simple fix to just change the registration of your function from `computed` to `methods` which it really is.

```
methods: {
       fullName: function (user) {
            return user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name;
        }

    }
```

This way you will not have to change any of your other code.

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks. Just simple as that. I think :)

Answer (score 23):

Try to disable cache on the computed property, like mentioned in https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1189. Doing this, the computed value will be always recalculated.

```
computed: {
  fullName: {
    cache: false,
    get() {
      return user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but in this case. where is user come from?

Comment: Now deprecated: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#cache-false-deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Computed properties don't support nesting like that.

Proof and some workarounds/alternative solutions: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/66

Answer (score 2):

You can map the users in your computed property and use that mapped array like this:

```
computed: {
  fullName: function () {
    return this.users.map(
      item => item.first_name + ' ' + item.last_name
    );
  }
}
```

Then in view you can do something like:

```
<tr v-for="(user, item) in users">
   <td class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
     {{fullName[item]}} 
   </td>
<tr>
```

And I am using es6 arrow function. If you don't want to use arrow function then you can do something like:

```
return this.users.map(
  function(item) {return item.first_name + ' ' +item.last_name}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar case, when i use a props property with undecleared nested properties. For some reason i made this work doing a

`console.log(user.first_name)`

> ```
>        fullName: function (user) {
>             console.log(user.first_name)
>             return user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name;
>        }
> ```

Also, i made this work using lambda expression
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46234335/726751

```
computed: {
    fullName: _this => {
        return _this.user.first_name + ' ' + _this.user.last_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another reason: properties with an underscore (`_`) prefix will not trigger `computed`.

Surprise: `_` and `$` prefixes are [reserved in Vue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5879).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar question here: [How to dinamically make computed in Vue.js, under dynamically loaded data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222405/how-to-dinamically-make-computed-in-vue-js-under-dynamically-loaded-data?noredirect=1#comment89457387_51222405).

But, in the end here is the possible solution for you from the conclusion that i get after discussing and trial and error. There are several ways:

1. create extender that assign the computed inside each element, then call it using `item.computedProperty()` in the UI (with double bracket)
2. assume the data is loaded, for example `items`, create a watcher that will assign the computed to each of the element, then put inside `extendedItems`. the computed function will become reactive when bound to UI, so the UI then will use `extendedItems` instead of `items`
3. use vue's `this.$set` to manually set and enable reactivity to the computed.

This is using computed with function from the solution number 1:

```
new Vue({

    el: '#content',

    data: {
      "users": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "first_name": "Joe",
          "last_name": "Blogs"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "first_name": "Jane",
          "last_name": "Doe"
        }
      ]
   },
    computed: {
        extendedUsers: function(){
            var users = this.users;
            for (var i in users)
                this.extendUser(users[i])

        },
        extendUser: function(user){
            user.fullName = function(){
                return user.first_name + " " + user.last_name;
            }
        }

    }

});



<tr v-for="user in users | orderBy user.fullName()">
      <td class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
          {{user.fullName()}} 
     </td>
<tr>
```