# How to dinamically make computed in Vue.js, under dynamically loaded data

Tags: vue.js

I my background is knockout.js. In knockout i can do something like this:

```js
var observable = ko.observable;
var pureComputed = ko.pureComputed;
var observableArray = ko.observableArray;

var koRoles = observableArray([]);
var koUsers = observableArray([]);



function loadUsersFromApi(){
  //assume this is async function
  var users = [{
    name: "this is the name",
    roles: ["role1","role2"]
  },{
    name: "another user",
    roles: ["role1"]
  }];
  for (var i in users)
    extendUser(users[i]);
  koUsers(users)
}

function extendUser(user){
    user.roleSummary = pureComputed(function(){
        return summarizeUserRole(user);
    })
}

function summarizeUserRole(user){
    var roles = koRoles();
    var result = [];
    var userRoles = user.roles;
    for (var i in userRoles){
        var userRole = userRoles[i];
        for (var j in roles)
          if (userRole == roles[j].id){
              result.push(roles[j].name);
              break;
          }
    }
    return result.join(", ");
}

function loadRolesFromApi(){
  //assume this is async function
  var roles = [{
    id: "role1",
    name: "Role 1"
  },{
    id: "role2",
    name: "Role 2",
  }]
  koRoles(roles);
}

ko.applyBindings({
    users: koUsers,
})

loadUsersFromApi();
loadRolesFromApi();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="user-list">
    <table>
        <thead>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Roles</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: users">
          <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: roleSummary"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

i want to highlight the `function extendUser(user)`, in this instance, i can extend the object and put a pure computed in knockout and it will refresh even though in the case that `koRoles(roles)` is finished later. So i want to know how to do this in Vue.JS. Currently I have something like this:

```
<td class="common__center-align">{{ item.roleSummary }}</td>
```

and in my component, i have this:

```
function extendUser(user){

        user.roleSummary = this.roleSummary(user);

}
```

and in the component on methods

```
methods: {roleSummary}
```

with `roleSummary` is the same logic as the one in knockout version, but this roleSummary can't become computed property. So, how to make this somewhat computed in Vue.js?

i know another alternative with the following method:
- make a component for `userRow` and settle it inside
- make sure roles loaded first then just load user

any other solution? but still i want to know how to make a computed in Vue.js dinamically.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want.  Do you want to use `v-for` to loop an array ? And each item has its own computed, then it can calculate data and show it on Html ?

Comment: yes! correct, it's something like that, so after loading list of data from server, i want to extend each of the entity and show it in array, so for example, the entity will have computed ```canEdit``` and ```canDelete```, based on certain logic, then whether i want to show or hide the edit and delte button. I foudn out that this can be done by doing ```v-if="item.computedField()"``` (adding the double bracket), but i wonder if there is a better way to do this or not

Comment: You found out a good way. I actually no better way to do that in your case. But if the requirement is as you said, it seems doesn't need to use `computed`.  You could just calculate data after the Ajax get a response.

Comment: Really this is the only way? the thing is, for example list of user, i want to summarize the role just like above. Both the user and role are ajax request. it's not guaranteed which one come first. So, i end up have to either use ```computed``` way like that, or make a computed in the component, check if both finished loaded or not, if both has been loaded, then just do the calculation and return the whole array, otherwise just return empty array

Comment: Yes, it is, in my view.  I think `computed` is easy to solve what you want. There still has another way, you could wait for more than 1 response complete, and then calculate the response data. It can achieve by the `axios` library easily.

Comment: Although `axios` can make programing structure more clear, but `computed` can let users to see view more fast but not full.

Comment: it's fine then i will just stick with computed instead